I need to transfer data between my temporary widget and mainwindow widget
I've been trying to figure out how to transfer data from one widget to another. I have two widgets, one takes data, another should receive it and call inside functions with received data.
Here's my code:
mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "init.h"


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void PaymentMethodSwap();
    void PaymentTimeSwap();
    void updateTotal();
    void PushToTable(int index, std::string name, double quantity, double price);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
public slots:
    void receive_data(DataSet&);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H



mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "tips.h"
#include "needs.h"
#include "positionpick.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    updateTotal();

    int wdt[4] {25, 135, 65, 50};
    auto table = ui->tableWidget;
    for (int i =0; i<4; i++){
        table->setColumnWidth(i, wdt[i]);
    }

    connect(ui->soupButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){PositionPick *w = new PositionPick; w->setWindowTitle(w->windowTitle()+" - Супы"); w->setCategory(0); w->show();});
    connect(ui->secondButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){PositionPick *w = new PositionPick; w->setWindowTitle(w->windowTitle()+" - Вторые блюда"); w->setCategory(1); w->show();});
    connect(ui->traditionalButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){PositionPick *w = new PositionPick; w->setWindowTitle(w->windowTitle()+" - Традиционные блюда"); w->setCategory(2); w->show();});
    connect(ui->topDishesButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){PositionPick *w = new PositionPick; w->setWindowTitle(w->windowTitle()+" - Блюда месяца"); w->setCategory(3); w->show();});
    connect(ui->customButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){PositionPick *w = new PositionPick; w->setWindowTitle(w->windowTitle()+" - Свой рецепт"); w->setCategory(4); w->show();});
    connect(ui->sweetButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){PositionPick *w = new PositionPick; w->setWindowTitle(w->windowTitle()+" - Десерты"); w->setCategory(5); w->show();});


    connect(ui->tipsButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){Tips *tip = new Tips; tip->show();});
    connect(ui->payOptionMethod,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            &MainWindow::PaymentMethodSwap);
    connect(ui->payOptionTime,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            &MainWindow::PaymentTimeSwap);
    connect(ui->needsButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){Needs *need = new Needs; need->show();});
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::updateTotal(){
    ui->totalValue->setText(QString::number(currTransaction.getSum(), 'f', 2));
}

void MainWindow::PushToTable(int index, std::string name, double quantity, double price){
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(index));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(name.c_str()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(quantity));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, 3, new QTableWidgetItem(price));
}

void MainWindow::PaymentMethodSwap(){
    std::string text1 = "Оплата:\nналичными", text2 = "Оплата:\nкартой";
    if (ui->payOptionMethod->text() == text1.c_str()) ui->payOptionMethod->setText(text2.c_str());
    else ui->payOptionMethod->setText(text1.c_str());
}

void MainWindow::PaymentTimeSwap(){
    std::string text1 = "Оплата:\nсразу", text2 = "Оплата:\nпосле";
    if (ui->payOptionTime->text() == text1.c_str()) ui->payOptionTime->setText(text2.c_str());
    else ui->payOptionTime->setText(text1.c_str());
}
void MainWindow::receive_data(DataSet& data){
    std::cout << data.index;
}


positionpick.h
#ifndef POSITIONPICK_H
#define POSITIONPICK_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <fstream>
#include "init.h"


namespace Ui {
class PositionPick;
}

class PositionPick : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PositionPick(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~PositionPick();
    void setCategory(int);
    void addPositions();
private:
    Ui::PositionPick *ui;
    std::string category;
signals:
    void dataChanged(DataSet&);
};


#endif // POSITIONPICK_H


positionpick.cpp
#include "positionpick.h"
#include "ui_positionpick.h"
#include "CSVRow.h"

PositionPick::PositionPick(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::PositionPick)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    addPositions();

    connect(ui->resetButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){ui->quantity->setValue(1);});
    connect(ui->closeButton,
            &QPushButton::clicked,
            this,
            [=](){this->close();});
}

PositionPick::~PositionPick()
{
    delete ui;
}

void PositionPick::setCategory(int cat){
    switch (cat){
    case 0: category = "soups"; break;
    case 1: category = "seconds"; break;
    case 2: category = "traditional"; break;
    case 3: category = "topDishes"; break;
    case 4: category = "custom"; break;
    case 5: category = "sweets"; break;
    default: break;
    }
}

void PositionPick::addPositions(){
    std::ifstream file(":/foodbase/menu/"+ category + ".csv");
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data = readCSV(file);
    int index = 0;
    std::string btnName;
    std::vector<int> {};
    for(unsigned long long int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++){
        QPushButton *newbutton = new QPushButton;
        newbutton->resize(190, 190);
        newbutton->setText(data[i][0].c_str());
        btnName = ("Button" + std::to_string(index));
        newbutton->setObjectName(btnName.c_str());
        newbutton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\
                                 color: white;\
                                 background-color: #000033;\
                                 border: 1px solid black;\
                                 border-radius: 7px;\
                             }\
                             QPushButton:hover{\
                                 background-color: rgb(92, 100, 150);\
                             }\
                             QPushButton:pressed{\
                                 background-color:rgb(0, 0, 30);\
                                 border: 3px inset\
                             }");
        newbutton->setParent(ui->ParentWidget);
        newbutton->move(5 + i*192, 5+abs(index/3)*192);
        connect(ui->ParentWidget->findChild<QPushButton *>(btnName.c_str()),
                &QPushButton::clicked,
                this,
                [=](){currTransaction.addPosition(std::stod(data[i][1]), ui->quantity->text().toDouble()); });
        index++;
    }
}


I need to transfer data from positionpick (index, name, quantity and price) to mainwindow, to call PushToTable method. Help me please. Thanks in advance.
I'm pretty new to qt so i stuck at signals and slots, i've tried to create signal at my taking data-widget and receiving it at mainwindow widget, yet it did not succeed.

Add a signals: block to PositionPick and modify addPositions to emit that signal. Modify MainWindow to connect a slot to the PositionPick's signal. Show us what you tried.

@Botje i already tried that, i called QObject::connect function and gave all the parameters but it didn't work (i had signals: and slots: in my classes)

Edit your question with what you tried and what error message you got.

@Botje just added signal and slot, i don't actually know what to do next... At least, it didn't break anything.

Sounds like you need to read up on "Signals & Slots".  You declare a signal PositionPick::dataChanged but you never emit it.  Similarly you never connect that signal to the slot MainWindow::receive_data (assuming that's what you're trying to do).

Please create a [mcve], i.e. remove all code that is not strictly necessary to demonstrate your issue.

I don't know what this DataSet class is or does so I will just show you how to emit all variables separately.
For starters, add a signal to PositionPick:
signals:
void addToTransaction(int index, QString name, double quantity, double price);

Next, modify addPositions like so:
void PositionPick::addPositions(){
    std::ifstream file(":/foodbase/menu/"+ category + ".csv");
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> data = readCSV(file);
    int index = 0;
    for(unsigned long long int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++){
        QPushButton *newbutton = new QPushButton;
        newbutton->resize(190, 190);
        QString name = QString::fromStdString(data[i][0]); // this is how you convert std::string to QString
        newbutton->setText(name);  
        newbutton->setObjectName(QString("Button%1").arg(index));
        newbutton->setStyleSheet(/*elided for brevity*/);
        newbutton->setParent(ui->ParentWidget);
        newbutton->move(5 + i*192, 5+abs(index/3)*192);

        double unitPrice = /* fill in. data[i][2] maybe? */;
        connect(newButton,
                &QPushButton::clicked,
                this,
                [=](){ // This lambda captures the current value of index, name and unitPrice.
                  double quantity = ui->quantity->value();
                  emit addToTransaction(index, name, quantity, quantity * unitPrice);
                });
        index++;
    }
}

Next, hook up the widget to your window by calling
QObject::connect(w, &PositionPick::addToTransaction, &MainWindow::PushToTable);

right after you construct a PositionPick object.
Finally, make MainWindow::addToTransaction a slot.

Some other remarks: See if you can make ui->ParentWidget a QGridLayout or similar so you do not have to calculate positions yourself. Write meaningful named helper methods instead of copypasting the same line 7 times. And read the documentation on QString. It is everywhere in Qt and has tons of utility functions, especially for converting to and from other string types.
